# ArgumentError: Index name ... is too long; the limit is 62 characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I created a scaffold with this command (Rails 5.2.1.1):

```
rails g scaffold EmailAddress value:string:index 
                              email_address_type:references 
                              email_addressable:references{polymorphic} 
                              position:integer
```

which resulted in this migration file:

```
class CreateEmailAddresses < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :email_addresses do |t|
      t.string :value
      t.references :email_address_type, foreign_key: true
      t.references :email_addressable, polymorphic: true
      t.integer :position

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :email_addresses, :value
  end
end
```

Unfortunately this raises the following error on `rails db:migrate`:

```
Caused by:
ArgumentError: Index name
'index_email_addresses_on_email_addressable_type_and_email_addressa...' 
on table 'email_addresses' is too long; the limit is 62 characters
```

I understand the problem and the error. I'm wondering what the best solution is because the index is not set explicity by `add_index` but by some background magic.

Comment: `add_index :email_addresses, :value, name: '<index name>' `

Comment: I added `add_index :email_addresses, [:email_addressable_type, :email_addressable_id], name: 'email_addressable_index'`and get the same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Wintermeyer says is one solution, there is another way at least I find smoother to use.

```
 t.references :email_address_type, foreign_key: true, 
                                   index: { name: "addressable_index" }
```

Through this you dont get a bunch of `add_index` rows in your migration. This helps if you ever have a large migration and need to find a specific index quickly. This is just my personal opinion, Wintermeyer solution is also a working fix!

Answer (score 2):

`index: false` is the solution for this problem. Followed by an `add_index` at the bottom. Here is the migration:

```
class CreateEmailAddresses < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :email_addresses do |t|
      t.string :value
      t.references :email_address_type, foreign_key: true
      t.references :email_addressable, polymorphic: true, index: false
      t.integer :position

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :email_addresses, :value
    add_index :email_addresses, [:email_addressable_type, 
                                :email_addressable_id], 
                                name: 'email_addressable_index'
  end
end
```